# How to change the edge color of markers (patches) in Matplotlib legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, marker

I know the hatch color follows the edge color when plot bars, so I have plotted the bars twice to decouple the hatch color and edge color. Although this method works in bars, I don't know how to change the edge color of markers in legend, to make the markers in legend be consistent with bars.
Here are my code and plotted picture. I want to make the markers in legend also have black edges like bars.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['pdf.fonttype'] = 42
matplotlib.rcParams['ps.fonttype'] = 42
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

x_lable = ['3', '4', '5', '6', '7']

width = 0.3

data_1 = [2228, 2621, 3165, 3761, 3763]
data_2 = [3895, 5670, 7354, 8999, 10731]
data_3 = [4355, 6373, 8279, 10105, 12018]

xcoordinate = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
xcoordinate_1 = [xcoordinate[0] + 0 * width, xcoordinate[1] + 0 * width, xcoordinate[2] + 0 * width, xcoordinate[3] + 0 * width, xcoordinate[4] + 0 * width]
xcoordinate_2 = [xcoordinate[0] + 1 * width, xcoordinate[1] + 1 * width, xcoordinate[2] + 1 * width, xcoordinate[3] + 1 * width, xcoordinate[4] + 1 * width]
xcoordinate_3 = [xcoordinate[0] + 2 * width, xcoordinate[1] + 2 * width, xcoordinate[2] + 2 * width, xcoordinate[3] + 2 * width, xcoordinate[4] + 2 * width]
xcoordinate_4 = [xcoordinate[0] + 3 * width, xcoordinate[1] + 3 * width, xcoordinate[2] + 3 * width, xcoordinate[3] + 3 * width, xcoordinate[4] + 3 * width]
xcoordinate_5 = [xcoordinate[0] + 4 * width, xcoordinate[1] + 4 * width, xcoordinate[2] + 4 * width, xcoordinate[3] + 4 * width, xcoordinate[4] + 4 * width]

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.bar(xcoordinate_3, data_1, width=width, label='GGG', color='none', edgecolor='orange', hatch='\\\\\\')
ax1.bar(xcoordinate_4, data_2, width=width, label='SSS', color='none', edgecolor='blue', hatch='---')
ax1.bar(xcoordinate_5, data_3, width=width, label='KKK', color='none', edgecolor='orangered', hatch='///')

fmt='%.2f%%'
yticks = mtick.FormatStrFormatter(fmt)

ax1.set_ylabel('AAA')

ax1.set_xlabel('BBB')

plt.xticks([i + 3 * width for i in xcoordinate], x_lable)

ax1.bar(xcoordinate_3, data_1, width=width, label='GGG', color='none', edgecolor='black')
ax1.bar(xcoordinate_4, data_2, width=width, label='SSS', color='none', edgecolor='black')
ax1.bar(xcoordinate_5, data_3, width=width, label='KKK', color='none', edgecolor='black')

handles1, labels1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
order = [0, 1, 2]
plt.legend([handles1[idx] for idx in order], [labels1[idx] for idx in order],  loc=(2.5/10, 1.01),  frameon=True, ncol=3, shadow=False, framealpha=1, labelspacing=1,handlelength=2).get_frame().set_edgecolor('black')

plt.show()
```

[image: plotted picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the second handle:

```
order = [0, 1, 2]
plt.legend([handles1[idx]+handles1[idx+3] for idx in order], [labels1[idx] for idx in order],  loc=(2.5/10, 1.01),  frameon=True, ncol=3, shadow=False, framealpha=1, labelspacing=1,handlelength=2).get_frame().set_edgecolor('black')
```

Sample output:
[image]